# C++ equivalent for C-style array

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization

I have heard a lot of guys here saying that C++ is as fast or *faster* than C in everything, but cleaner and nicer.

While I do not contradict the fact that C++ is very elegant, and quite fast, I did not find any replacement for critical memory access or processor-bound applications.

**Question**: is there an equivalent in C++ for C-style arrays in terms of performance?

The example below is contrived, but I am interested in the solution for real-life problems: I develop image processing apps, and the amount of pixel processing there is huge.

```
double t;

// C++ 
std::vector<int> v;
v.resize(1000000,1);
int i, j, count = 0, size = v.size();

t = (double)getTickCount();

for(j=0;j<1000;j++)
{
    count = 0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
         count += v[i];     
}

t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
std::cout << "(C++) For loop time [s]: " << t/1.0 << std::endl;
std::cout << count << std::endl;

// C-style

#define ARR_SIZE 1000000

int* arr = (int*)malloc( ARR_SIZE * sizeof(int) );

int ci, cj, ccount = 0, csize = ARR_SIZE;

for(ci=0;ci<csize;ci++)
    arr[ci] = 1;

t = (double)getTickCount();

for(cj=0;cj<1000;cj++)
{
    ccount = 0;
    for(ci=0;ci<csize;ci++)
        ccount += arr[ci];      
}

free(arr);

t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
std::cout << "(C) For loop time [s]: " << t/1.0 << std::endl;
std::cout << ccount << std::endl;
```

Here is the result:

```
(C++) For loop time [s]: 0.329069

(C) For loop time [s]: 0.229961
```

Note: `getTickCount()` comes from a third-party lib. If you want to test, just replace with your favourite clock measurement

**Update:**

I am using VS 2010, Release mode, everything else default

Comment: Which compiler and options did you use? Usually an stl vector with some optimizations enabled has exactly the code for [] than an array.

Comment: I doubt you did a full-optimization C++ build.

Comment: There is no pointer array in this code ...

Comment: I just tested this (with slightly modified code, on one computer, with one particular compiler). Without optimisations, the "C++ style" one is about one third slower than the "C style" one. With optimisations, the "C++ style" one is consistently _slightly_ faster than the "C style" one (and both are much faster than without optimisation).

Comment: @vasile: Out of interest, have you also tried building the C code with your C++ compiler and profiling that? (assuming the compilers are different.)

Comment: I get .215 seconds for both the C and C++ versions on my machine. (GCC and G++ on x86-64 machine). C++ is faster 32-bit, for some reason (.534/.605).

Comment: I get the same runtime for both versions when compiling with g++ -O3.

Comment: Ok, as stated in update, I use MSVC 2010, Release, other options as default. It seems that other compilers give different results

Comment: I also get the same time for both version. Compiled with clang++ -Os with libc++, 32 bit.

Comment: @vasile: So you're measuring MSVC2010's code generation and optimization.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Question: is there an equivalent in C++ for C-style arrays in terms of performance?

Answer: Write C++ code! Know your language, know your standard library and use it. Standard algorithms are correct, readable and fast (They know the best how to implement it to be fast on the current compiler).

```
void testC()
{
    // unchanged
}

void testCpp()
{
    // unchanged initialization

    for(j=0;j<1000;j++)
    {
        // how a C++ programmer accumulates:
        count = std::accumulate(begin(v), end(v), 0);    
    }

    // unchanged output
}

int main()
{
    testC();
    testCpp();
}
```

Output:

```
(C) For loop time [ms]: 434.373
1000000
(C++) For loop time [ms]: 419.79
1000000
```

Compiled with `g++ -O3 -std=c++0x` Version 4.6.3 on Ubuntu.

For your code my output is similiar to yours. user1202136 gives a good answer about the differences...

Comment: could you post your time profiling code? I am getting pretty strange results when I use std::accumulate.

Comment: @juanchopanza I used `gettimeofday` from `<sys/time.h>`

Comment: I think this is the answer... although on my test platform (MSVC) it's slower than everything else. But I cannot blame C++ for what seems to be Microsoft's fault

Answer (score 13):

Simple answer: Your benchmark is flawed.

Longer answer: You need to turn on full optimization to get C++ performance advantage. Yet your benchmark is still flawed.

Some observations:

1. If you turn on full optimization, a very large chunk of for-loop would be removed. This make your benchmark meaningless.
2. `std::vector` have overhead for dynamic reallocation, try `std::array`. 

   To be specific, microsoft's stl have [checked iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985896%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) by default.
3. You don't have any barrier to prevent cross reordering between C / C++ code / benchmark code.
4. (not really related) `cout << ccount` is locale aware, `printf` is not;  `std::endl` flush the output, `printf("\n")` don't.

The "traditional" code for showing c++ advantage is C `qsort()` vs C++ `std::sort()`. This is where code inlineing shines.

If you want some "real-life" application example. Search for some raytracer or matrix multiplication stuff. Pick an compiler that do auto vectorization.

**Update**
Using the [LLVM online demo](http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi), we can see the whole loop is reordered. The benchmark code is moved to start, and it jump to the loop ending point in the first loop for better branch prediction:

(this is c++ code)

```
######### jump to the loop end
    jg  .LBB0_11
.LBB0_3:                                # %..split_crit_edge
.Ltmp2:
# print the benchmark result
    movl    $0, 12(%esp)
    movl    $25, 8(%esp)
    movl    $.L.str, 4(%esp)
    movl    std::cout, (%esp)
    calll   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
.Ltmp3:
# BB#4:                                 # %_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.exit
.Ltmp4:
    movl    std::cout, (%esp)
    calll   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<double>(double)
.Ltmp5:
# BB#5:                                 # %_ZNSolsEd.exit
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, 28(%esp)          # 4-byte Spill
    movl    (%ecx), %eax
    movl    -24(%eax), %eax
    movl    240(%eax,%ecx), %ebp
    testl   %ebp, %ebp
    jne .LBB0_7
# BB#6:
.Ltmp52:
    calll   std::__throw_bad_cast()
.Ltmp53:
.LBB0_7:                                # %.noexc41
    cmpb    $0, 28(%ebp)
    je  .LBB0_15
# BB#8:
    movb    39(%ebp), %al
    jmp .LBB0_21
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_9:                                #   Parent Loop BB0_11 Depth=1
                                        # =>  This Inner Loop Header: Depth=2
    addl    (%edi,%edx,4), %ebx
    addl    $1, %edx
    adcl    $0, %esi
    cmpl    %ecx, %edx
    jne .LBB0_9
# BB#10:                                #   in Loop: Header=BB0_11 Depth=1
    incl    %eax
    cmpl    $1000, %eax             # imm = 0x3E8
######### jump back to the print benchmark code
    je  .LBB0_3
```

My test code:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.resize(1000000,1);
int i, j, count = 0, size = v.size();

for(j=0;j<1000;j++)
{
    count = 0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
         count += v[i];     
}

std::cout << "(C++) For loop time [s]: " << t/1.0 << std::endl;
std::cout << count << std::endl;
```

Comment: Hmmm, I have used default Release mode in MSVC. And I tried to get out of the loop all the allocation/ output, etc. std::cout is strategically out of the benchmark. It rather seems to be a compiler problem, 'cause g++ gives equal times for both codes

Comment: Are you saying he's "holding it wrong"? His code is a valid benchmark and it should generate the same instructions for both languages. That it is not points to a problem in the compiler or the STL.

Comment: (2) is not true. The array is resized in advance before the time checking, so no reallocation is performed. As to (1) I'd (partially) unwind the loop (to reduce loop-related stuff) and make count volatile to exclude undesired optimization

Comment: @user396672, making `ccount` volatile would prevent vectorization as well. We need to stop loop-inversion/elimination, not vectorization.

Comment: @user396672, for (2): in microsoft's stl, the default `operator[]` checks for bounds. (`_SECURE_SCL`)

Comment: @J-16SDiZ In 2010 the default value of _SECURE_SCL is 0  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985896.aspx

Comment: @J-16SDiZ oops :-)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985896(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: printf is be locale aware as well.

Comment: and printf usually also flushes when presented with `'\n'`.

Answer (score 8):

It seems to be a compiler problem. For C-arrays, the compiler detects the pattern, uses auto-vectorization and emits SSE instructions. For vector, it seems to lack the necessary intelligence.

If I force the compiler not to use SSE, the results are very similar (tested with `g++ -mno-mmx -mno-sse -msoft-float -O3`):

```
(C++) For loop time [us]: 604610
1000000
(C) For loop time [us]: 601493
1000000
```

Here is the code that generated this output. It is basically the code in your question, but without any floating point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

long getTickCount()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec * 1000000 + tv.tv_usec;
}

int main() {
long t;

// C++ 
std::vector<int> v;
v.resize(1000000,1);
int i, j, count = 0, size = v.size();

t = getTickCount();

for(j=0;j<1000;j++)
{
    count = 0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
         count += v[i];     
}

t = getTickCount() - t;
std::cout << "(C++) For loop time [us]: " << t << std::endl;
std::cout << count << std::endl;

// C-style

#define ARR_SIZE 1000000

int* arr = new int[ARR_SIZE];

int ci, cj, ccount = 0, csize = ARR_SIZE;

for(ci=0;ci<csize;ci++)
    arr[ci] = 1;

t = getTickCount();

for(cj=0;cj<1000;cj++)
{
    ccount = 0;
    for(ci=0;ci<csize;ci++)
        ccount += arr[ci];      
}

delete arr;

t = getTickCount() - t;
std::cout << "(C) For loop time [us]: " << t << std::endl;
std::cout << ccount << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with SSE or MMX. It's only about having optimization turned on. Also, gettimeofday() is a bad choice for benchmarking because it also records the time spent *outside* the  process. Use getrusage() if you are on unix.

Comment: @LutherBlissett I'm sorry, but SSE or MMX *is* the problem. I checked the assembler output. Optimizations were already turned on through `-O3`. I used `gettimeofday` as I heard `getrusage` had a bad resolution. To reduce benchmark error, I made sure the system was mostly idle and I ran the benchmark several times, with similar results.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ equivalent of a dynamically sized array would be `std::vector`. The C++ equivalent of a fixed size array would be `std::array` or `std::tr1::array` pre-C++11.

If your vector code has no re-sizings it is hard to see how it could be significantly slower than using a dynamically allocated C array, provided you compile with some optimization enabled.

Note: running the code as posted, compiled on gcc 4.4.3 on x86, compiler options

> g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -O2 -std=c++0x

the results are repeatably close to

> (C++) For loop time [us]: 507888
>
> 1000000
>
> (C) For loop time [us]: 496659
>
> 1000000

So, seemingly ~2% slower for the `std::vector` variant after a small number of trials. I'd consider this compatible performance.

Comment: The profiling starts after the vector is initialized, so that can't be the problem...

Comment: Resizing from zero is probably no different from allocating.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz *probably*, but it seems unnecessary and is a sign of not knowing much about std::vector.

Comment: ... but it is slower, so now what?

Comment: @LuboAntonov I need something I can test to prove that it is actually slower. Running my own version of the code compiled with gcc 4.6 and 4.8 I get the same performance for the C and C++ versions.

Comment: @LuboAntonov I have added some information concerning my own benchmarks. I don't know what else to say. It clearly depends on the compiler and the optimization flags.

Comment: The 2% number is misleading as it’s easily within the error margin. There should be *no* statistically significant difference between the two pieces of code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't want to speculate too much about what *should* be, but I admit I only ran the program ~10 times. In this mini-experiment, offset was consistent with 2%. But as far as I am concerned, the performance is the same. What I do find puzzling is the result with ``std::accumulate``.

Comment: @Juan Did you look at the assembly code? Maybe it auto-vectorises the code inside `accumulate`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph no, I didn't, but I suspected it might be doing that. It is almost too good to be true. Maybe I can use it to persuade my colleagues to use the standard library more often.

Comment: @SteveJessop I agree, but the return value is used, and printed to stdout.

Comment: @KonradRudolph mystery solved. It was all down to incompetence on my side. I missed the outer loop when using std::accumulate. With it, the results are compatible with and without accumulate.

Answer (score 0):

What you point out is the fact that accessing objects will always come with a little overhead, so accessing a `vector` won't be faster than accessing a good old array.

But even if using an array is "C-stylish", it remains C++ so it won't be a problem.

Then, as @juanchopanza said, there is `std::array` in C++11, which may be more efficient than `std::vector`, but specialized for fixed-size array.

Comment: "there is std::array in C++11, which is more efficient than std::vector." can you back this up?

Comment: Array is more efficient if you do operations on a vector that change its size, such as looping over `push_back` without `resize`.

Comment: `array` *may* be more efficient for example because `vector` involves an extra level of indirection (it contains a pointer to the data, while `array` contains the data). Yes, the compiler will hoist the reading of that data pointer outside the loop, but doing so costs you a register (to store it in), whereas accesses to a `std::array` can be based straight off the stack pointer. Using one register is a minor performance issue, but it might make a difference sometimes. For the same reason, `array` *may* be slower, because using more stack affects caching. "May" is an easy target to reach :-)

Comment: If nothing else, I would expect `std::array` to be faster in general due to stack allocation generally outperforming heap allocation, and `std::array` having one less pointer indirection, as you said. I would expect access through a pointer to a dynamically allocated `std::array` to be the same as access to a `std::vector`. At least in many of my domains, heap allocation / deallocation is the single biggest performance killer in general.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Compiler does all the optimization... You have just to choose a good compiler